# The central limit theorem and estimator in the task

Tags: statistics

I have problem with task:

Among 500 randomly selected articles found 25 faulty copies. Estimate (a confidence level of 0.95) the percentage of defective products throughout the production batch.

How to start solve this?

Comment: You know the sample mean, so all you need is the sample standard deviation. How do you get it?

Comment: How can I get standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the real proportion of defects, so you are estimating it with the sample proportion $\hat p$ that in your case equals $25/500$. 
Assuming that the articles are independent identically distributed with $\mathcal B er (p)$ each, thus you can approximate the sample average distribution with the Gaussian r.v., i.e., 
$$
\hat p \xrightarrow{D}N\left(p,\frac{p(1-p)}{n}\right).
$$

As such, the $95\%$ CI will be 
$$
\left[\hat p \pm Z_{0.975}\left(\frac{\hat p (1 - \hat p) }{n}\right)^{1/2}\right]
$$